# Change of query var in pre_get_posts not maintained

Tags: plugin-development, pre-get-posts, feed

I'm creating a plugin that adds a custom feed. I am using a `pre_get_posts` filter to change the `posts_per_page` query var to -1 (to get all items of a custom post type). However, if I dump the `$wp_query` in the render function, `posts_per_page` remains the default. I tested also changing `posts_per_rss` to -1, and I *do* see that as changed in the query (though it, of course, doesn't have any effect on the resulting posts). I also tried changing my theme to a default one and testing, but I had the same results. Can anyone explain why I can't change the `posts_per_page` query var?

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;

if(!class_exists('My_Custom_Feeds'))
{

    class My_Custom_Feeds { 

        protected $feed_slug = 'theslug';

        function __construct() {

            add_action( 'init', array($this, 'mcf_add_feed'));
            add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', array($this, 'mcf_pre_get_posts'));
        }

        function mcf_add_feed() {
            add_feed($this->feed_slug, array($this, 'mcf_render'));
        }

        function mcf_render(){

            //just output query to ensure it is as expected - but it's not
            global $wp_query;
            var_dump($wp_query);
            exit();
        }

        function mcf_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

            if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_feed( $this->feed_slug ) ) {

                // modify query here to show all posts
                $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1);
                $query->set( 'posts_per_rss', -1);
            }
        }
    }
}
if ( class_exists('My_Custom_Feeds') ){

    $my_custom_feeds = new My_Custom_Feeds();
}
```

---

**Update one:**
Realized I was using `add_filter` instead of `add_action` for `pre_get_posts`. I've updated that, though I still see the same issue.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array($this, 'mcf_pre_get_posts'));
```

---

**Update two (and final):**
Per @ialocin's answer, I realized changing the `posts_per_page` query var is futile since it is overwritten by the `posts_per_rss` option in a feed query (my scenario). So, the answer is to use a filter to alter that option. (-1 is not a valid `posts_per_rss` value, thus the arbitrary one used below.)

```
function mcf_posts_per_rss( $option_name ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->is_feed( $this->feed_slug ) ) {
            return 100; //arbitrarily large value that, while not ideal, works for me
    }
    return $option_name;
}
```

Then in my plugin class constructor I added the following (and removed the `pre_get_posts` action):

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_posts_per_rss', array( $this, 'mcf_posts_per_rss') );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the discussion/help in this thread, below is the basic code that ended up working for my purposes. Setting the `posts_per_page` query var was a futile exercise since it is overwritten by the `posts_per_rss` option in a feed query (my scenario). `posts_per_rss` is not a query var and must be set a different way, thus the `pre_option_posts_per_rss` filter added. (-1 is not a valid `posts_per_rss` value, thus the arbitrary one used below.)

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;

if(!class_exists('My_Custom_Feeds'))
{

    class My_Custom_Feeds { 

        protected $feed_slug = 'theslug';

        function __construct() {

            add_filter( 'pre_option_posts_per_rss', array( $this, 'mcf_posts_per_rss') );
            add_action( 'init', array($this, 'mcf_add_feed'));
        }

        function mcf_add_feed() {

            add_feed($this->feed_slug, array($this, 'mcf_render'));
        }

        function mcf_render(){

            //put rendering stuff here
            exit();
        }

        function mcf_posts_per_rss( $option_name ) {

            global $wp_query;
            if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->is_feed( $this->feed_slug ) ) {
                return 100; //arbitrarily large value that, while not ideal, worked for my purposes
            }
            return $option_name;
        }
    }
}
if ( class_exists('My_Custom_Feeds') ) {

    //instantiate class
    $my_custom_feeds = new My_Custom_Feeds();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[The `init` hook runs well before `pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request) so dumping the query at that point-- on `init`-- isn't going to reflect anything that will be done much later. I don't think there is anything wrong with your code, you misunderstand the sequence of actions. What you expect to happen isn't what actually happens.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, is there another action that I should add the feed on other than `init`? Otherwise, it sounds like I will have to requery in my render function and reset the post data after.

Comment: Adding the **feed** on `init` isn't the problem. Trying to dump `$wp_query` at that point **is**. The query will not be altered until later on `pre_get_posts`.  I don't think the problem is your functionality but that ***you are trying to test that functionality based on a flawed premise***.

Comment: Got it. But then my original question stands - why can't I change that query var? I continue to get only ten items rendered in the feed.

Answer (score 1):

`posts_per_rss` is **not** a [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) parameter. It is the name of the [`option`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) that is saved into the database. It can be addresses via the [`pre_option_{$option_name}`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_option_%28option_name%29):

```
function wpse191824_posts_per_rss( $option_name ) {
    return 999;
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_posts_per_rss', 'wpse191824_posts_per_rss' );
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm marking yours as the answer as it sent me down the path to figuring out my issue. I was originally setting `posts_per_rss` simply as a test, but doing some searching around this option I found out that the `posts_per_page` query var is overwritten by it if the query is in a feed. I also discovered that -1 is apparently not a valid `posts_per_rss` value, so I had to set it to an arbitrarily higher value for some scenarios. Will update my original post with the valid code.

Comment: My pleasure! You are right about the number. I'm guessing it is because the input at the form has `min="1"` set. Another thing, next time just post your solution as answer. It is how the system works. So you actually should do it - thanks. Then you can also always accept your own answer too. @Nicole